# why does my navigationItem.titleView not start in middle of my navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uilabel, navigationitem

I am trying to set the title of my navigation item by setting a UILabel to it. The code essentially works, but my is problem that when the View loads, for a second or so the UILabel starts at the position defined by the `CGRectMake` rather that at the top and middle of the navigation bar where it belongs. Is there a way to default having the UILabel start in the correct position?

The obvious work around is to set the initial position off the screen so it is hidden and then after a split second the UILabel moves to the correct place. but this seems to be the 'wrong' way to accomplish what I need. below is the code.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleView;
```

...

```
self.titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 128.0f)];
self.titleView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];
self.titleView.text = @"My title";
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Default alignment of text in `UILabel` is set to left, so you need to make it center programatically.

Try this,

```
self.titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 128.0f)];
self.titleView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];
self.titleView.text = @"My title";
[self.titleView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter]; //ADD THIS
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleView;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. My problem is not that the text is misaligned, but rather that the entire label is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f,44.0f)];
[self.titleView setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem like this way

```
UILabel * label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] autorelease];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
label.text = @"Customer"; //CUSTOM TITLE
[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Hey, so i added the autorelease but it gave me this error: "autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode"

Comment: remove the autorelease function!

Comment: lol, i thought that was the function which was supposed to fix my problem.